# ssh gatekeeper script and system calls

Tags: linux, ssh, perl

I'm using the [openssh gatekeeper script from calomel.org](https://calomel.org/openssh_gatekeeper.html) to make a semblance of two-factor authentication.

I've tried to use a curl to the localhost to send a randomly generated string via text message. The random string arrives just fine when I copy the modified `custom_string` subroutine into a separate test script but it does not work when used in the gatekeeper script.

```
sub custom_string {
    $maximum = 999999;
    my $x = int(rand($maximum));
    system "curl http://localhost/sendAuth.php?authCode=".$x;
    $code = $x;
}
```

Is it not working because I cannot use System commands from within the gatekeeper script?

Perhaps I cannot use network functions from within the script?

TLDR: Please tell me in which way I am ignorant.

Note: I'm also open to suggestions for getting the task done but that's secondary to learning what I've done wrong.

Other note: I am aware that `rand()` is not the best way to generate the random string I want. I am sketching out a proof of concept and will replace it once I have the fundamental design correct.

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting to get out of this? I don't see why it wouldn't work... but one thing you *aren't* doing is in any way collecting the results of `curl` in your script.

Perhaps something like:

```
my $response = `curl  http://localhost/sendAuth.php?authCode=".$x`;
print $response;
```

Might do what you want?

Although typically I'd suggest using the `LWP` module in perl for webby type operations, rather than running `curl` - it shouldn't be a problem in this case though.

Comment: The response is irrelevant unless it tells me it can't access the php script. The script is set up to send a text message to my phone. The point is that the same value is stored in the variable $code so that the ssh gatekeeper script will allow access when I input the value received in the text message. Unfortunately, the text message isn't being sent.